# Iterating a boost multi_array

Tags: c++, boost

I am having a problem with what I think should be an easy piece of code. I have a 2D array that is N x M, currently stored in a boost multi_array. The N columns represent spatial dimensions e.g. x,y,z and the M rows are points along each dimension.

What I would like to do is print all possible combinations of points along each dimension

For example, if my array is:

```
-1 -1
 1  1
```

I want to print:

```
-1 -1
 1 -1
-1  1
 1  1
```

I just cant make it work and I always go out of range on the array. I have tried using iterators and accessing the elements as A[i][j], but with no luck.
Anyone have any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Add at least your structure's code.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely not resetting the iterators by setting them back to begin().  A better strategy is not reusing the iterators at all.  Make them local to the loop that you're using them in.